# Log4j with arquillian on Websphere liberty profile

Tags: log4j, jboss-arquillian, websphere-liberty

I am trying to run arquillian on Websphere liberty profile. If I exclude log4j codes from my app test methods work properly.

But with the log4j.xml the test run ages and profile starts and not stops.
When I look at liberty profile logs I see the messages below:

And the whole example project is in this link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7QeE8UdXsczcnhQd1ZrelNMX0k

Thanks for advance

[17.12.2015 08:48:09:323 EET] 00000028 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [arquilliantestweb] [/arquilliantestweb] [org.arquillian.example.HelloWorldServlet]: Initialization successful.

[17.12.2015 08:48:09:371 EET] 00000028 SystemErr                                                    R log4j:WARN Could not find [log4j.dtd] using [com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader@d80c4c49] class loader, parsed without DTD.
[17.12.2015 08:48:09:372 EET] 00000028 SystemErr                                                    R log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 4 and column 50

Comment: Looks to me like Websphere is validating the xml it finds and because log4j uses a dtd if you don't have that dtd somewhere on the classpath it dies.

Comment: I have the dtd file at the same folder with log4j.xml